# Passing JSP parameters to spring controller

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, controller

I am having issues with passing values between jsp to controller..

my home.jsp includes another file check.jsp..

```
<jsp:include page="check.html" flush="true">
    <jsp:param name="param1" value="1" />
    <jsp:param name="param2" value="expert" />
    <jsp:param name="param3" value="skill"/>
</jsp:include>
```

and here is the controller...

```
@RequestMapping(value="check", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String checkList(ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletRequest request){
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("param1",request.getParameter("param1"));
    map.put("param2",request.getParameter("param2"));
    map.put("param3",request.getParameter("param3"));
    modelMap.addAllAttributes(map);
    return "checklist";
}
```

but I can't get the values in controller.. I mean all param values are null in the controller.. How to get these values?

Answer (score 0):

1. check != check.html
2. include != GET

That's why your params are empty.

Comment: @Michael.. changinf the requestmapping to check.html worked.. so how is that the controller was able to map the request before without .html but wasn't able to get the parameters?

Comment: Maybe you have something else in your app which I do not know. Maybe some default spring mapping for the urlbased view mapping.